# Ways To Save Bits of Javascript Code For Later Reference

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript (and programming) and I've been learning a lot over the past couple of months. I've written a few very simple apps, published a couple to the Play Store, and I have several more that I'm working on.

**I would like to know how everyone saves pieces of code that they want to re-use, or just reference, at a later date?**

For example, I've recently written a simple app that utilizes the fetch API as well as Javascript promises, and right now it's not hard to remember where I can locate that code for reference, because I've only written a few apps. However, in 2 years from now I may be trying to figure something out that I've already done before, and if I have a large number of apps that I've written, it may be quite difficult to remember which one contains the code that I need to reference.

Maybe my next project should be to figure out how to create my own searchable library ; )

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: JSFiddle or GIST for example. Give it a good title

Comment: Use a good version control such as Git, then you won't need to build yourself a searchable library,

Answer (score 1):

You can use github to upload you code with commits message and description.